# What is the tool that allows me to specify arbitrary directories using **

Tags: shell, command-line, directory, wildcards, recursive

I once saw a colleague uses a tool which allows to use ** to represent any directories. For example: if a file called `myfile.java` sits deep inside:

```
src/main/com/mycompany/product/store/myfile.java
```

A command in the parent of `src` directory:

```
ls **/myfile.java
```

can list the file.

Can anyone tell me what tool it is? What package I need to use on `Ubuntu` to achieve this?

Comment: I think it is a dirty shellhack, dots always need special treatment when they are in a specific role.

Comment: Hi. Sorry. I made a mistake. It is not ... but **. I have changed the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In bash ≥4.0, turn on the `globstar` option.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ echo pylib/**/pyerector.py
pylib/pyerector.py pylib/pyerector/pyerector.py
```

You can read more about it in the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

In zsh, this is available out of the box.

In ksh93, activate it with `set -o globstar`.

In plain sh or bash ≤3.x, this is not available.