# Find the total size of certain files within a directory branch

Tags: files, directory, directory-structure, size

Assume there's an image storage directory, say, `./photos/john_doe`, within which there are multiple subdirectories, where many certain files reside (say, `*.jpg`). How can I calculate a summary size of those files below the `john_doe` branch?

I tried `du -hs ./photos/john_doe/*/*.jpg`, but this shows individual files only. Also, this tracks only the first nest level of the `john_doe` directory, like `john_doe/june/`, but skips `john_doe/june/outrageous/`.

So, how could I traverse the entire branch, summing up the size of the certain files?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

```
find ./photos/john_doe -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$
```

If more than one invocation of `du` is required because the file list is very long, multiple totals will be reported and need to be summed.

Comment: find -iname 'file*' -exec du -cb {} + | grep total$ | cut -f1 | paste -sd+ - | bc

# summed byte size

Comment: If your system works under other language then you need to change total$ to other word like razem$ in Polish.

Comment: You can add `LC_ALL=POSIX` as prefix to always grep for total like this: `LC_ALL=POSIX find ./photos/john_doe -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$`

Comment: If you're not using `-name`, then change the grep to `grep -P "\ttotal$"` or else it will capture all files ending with "total" as well.

Comment: @MichalČizmazia some shells (e.g., Git Bash for Windows) don't come with `bc`, so here is a more portable solution: `find -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec du -bc {} + | grep total$ | cut -f1 | awk '{ total += $1 }; END { print total }'`

Comment: why not invert grep so it works for all languages? `...|grep -v .jpg$`

Comment: What does the `+` do at the end of the `find` command? I couldn't find any mention of it in `man find`.

Comment: When totals come with units at end `bc` does not operate well, it is better to use: `find -iname 'file*' -exec du -cb {} + |grep -e "total$" |cut -f1 |paste -sd+ - |bc |numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --round=towards-zero`

Comment: This is the most portable, flexible, Unix-like answer that gets close. Every other answer either doesn't answer the question or works only with `bash` or Linux or GNU `find`.

Comment: @localhost: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085237/785194

Answer (score 107):

```
du -ch public_html/images/*.jpg | grep total
20M total
```

gives me the total usage of my `.jpg` files in this directory.

To deal with multiple directories you'd probably have to combine this with `find` somehow.

You might find [du command examples](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-du-command-examples.html) useful (it also includes `find`)

Comment: This doesn't traverse the underlying directories?

Comment: This is easier to type than the accepted solution, but is only half-right, it won't include images in subdirectories. Good to know if all the files are in one directory.

Comment: @gbmhunter I think if you add the -R parameter to -ch you will also get the subdirectories as it recursively traverses the directory tree. I'm not currently at a computer to try it out though to confirm.

Comment: I don't see an `-R` option at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html. And I don't think a recursive option would help in this case because the shell is doing the glob expansion before passing the arguments to `du`.

Comment: To get images in subdirectories, couldn't you use `**/*.jpg`?

Comment: Even for ` du -hc *.gz` it's giving me `-bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long` error

Comment: the same here: invert grep to work in all languages: `...|grep -v .jpg$`

Comment: Note that this throws things off if you have `total` in a file name. Might make more sense to replace `| grep total` with `| tail -n1`

Answer (score 51):

Primarily, you need two things:

- the `-c` option to `du`, to tell it to produce a grand total;
- either `**` ([activation instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/what-is-the-tool-that-allows-me-to-specify-arbitrary-directories-using)) or `find` ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41550/find-the-total-size-of-certain-files-within-a-directory-branch/41552#41552)) or  to traverse subdirectories.

```
du -ch -- **/*.jpg | tail -n 1
```

Comment: very good reply. Simpler than using find (as long * or ** matches the directory structure)

Comment: It can also handle very long lists of files whereas using `find` can return erroneous results.

Comment: bash brace expansion allows for measuring multiple sets of wildcards too. `du -ch -- ./{dir1,dir2}/*.jpg` or `du -ch -- ./{prefix1*,prefix2*}.jpg`

Comment: @EricFournie However I got `Argument list too long` error when processing about 300k text files.

Comment: The maximum number of arguments for a command (in this case, the file names returned by the wildcard expansion) can be checked with `getconf ARG_MAX`. If you have more, you will need to process the files one by one or batchwise with a for loop.

Comment: I was getting "No such file or directory" errors when using the ```**/*``` glob, but then spotted the link you had to globstar in your answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: +1 for `-c`.  I can't imagine how I forgot that. Fortunately here in the future we can use `--total` now. which I probably won't remember either...

Answer (score 45):

The ultimate answer is:

```
{ find <DIR> -type f -name "*.<EXT>" -printf "%s+"; echo 0; } | bc
```

and even faster version, not limited by RAM, but that requires GNU AWK with bignum support:

```
find <DIR> -type f -name "*.<EXT>" -printf "%s\n" | gawk -M '{t+=$1}END{print t}'
```

This version has the following features:

- all capabilities of `find` to specify the files you're looking for
- supports millions of files

  - other answers here are limited by the maximum length of the argument list
- spawns only 3 simple processes with a minimal pipe throughput

  - many answers here spawn C+N processes, where C is some constant and N is the number of files
- doesn't bother with string manipulation

  - this version doesn't do any grepping, or regexing
  - well, `find` does a simple wildcard matching of filenames
- optionally formats the sum into a human-readable form (eg. `5.5K`, `176.7M`, ...)

  - to do that append `| numfmt --to=si`

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, although it only worked for me when I introduced spaces after the opening brace and before the closing brace. I do wonder if it will really support an 'infiinte' number of files though :)

Comment: @andyb thanks for the feedback, the spaces around braces are indeed required in BASH, I'm using ZSH so I didn't notice that. And the number of files is limited by the available RAM on your system as bc's memory usage grows slowly as the numbers flow in.

Answer (score 17):

The answers given until now do not take into account that the file list passed from find to du may be so long that find automatically splits the list into chunks, resulting in multiple occurences of `total`.

You can either `grep total` (locale!) and sum up manually, or use a different command. AFAIK there are only two ways to get a grand total (in kilobytes) of all files found by find:
`find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -r0 du -a| awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`

Explanation
`find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0`: Find all files with the extension jpg regardless of case (i.e. *.jpg, *.JPG, *.Jpg...) and output them (null-terminated).
`xargs -r0 du -a`: 
-r: Xargs would call the command even with no arguments passed, which -r prevents. -0 means null-terminated strings (not newline terminated).
`awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`: Sum up the file sizes output by the previous command

And for reference, the other way would be
`find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | du -c --files0-from=-`

Comment: Additional hint: On my HDD with 23428 files (22323 being images) the first method runs 1 sec while the second one runs 3.8 secs.

Comment: Note that both assume a GNU system. The first one assumes file names don't contain newline characters.

Comment: I'd bet the `du --file0-from` took longer because you ran it first (caching effect).

Comment: With `xargs`, several `du -a` may be run, so you may have discrepancies if there are hard links.

Answer (score 4):

If the list of files is too big that it can't be passed to a single invocation of `du -c`, on a GNU system, you can do:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -type f -printf '%b\t%D:%i\n' |
  sort -u | cut -f1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

(size expressed in number of 512 byte blocks). Like `du` it tries to count hard links only once. If you don't care about hardlinks, you can simplify it to:

```
(printf 0; find . -iname '*.jpg' -type f -printf +%b) | bc
```

If you want the size instead of disk usage, replace `%b` with `%s`. The size will then be expressed in bytes.

Comment: `-bash: bc: command not found`
Centos - Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Comment: @yeya, sounds like your CentOS deployment is broken. `bc` is a non-optional POSIX command.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions mentioned so far are inefficient (exec is expensive) and require additional manual work to sum if the file list is long or they don't work on Mac OS X. The following solution is very fast, should work on any system, and yields the total answer in GB (remove a /1024 if you want to see the total in MB):

`find . -iname "*.jpg" -ls |perl -lane '$t += $F[6]; print $t/1024/1024/1024 . " GB"'`

Comment: Neither `-iname` nor `-ls` are standard/portable, so it won't _work on any system_ either. It will also not work properly if there are filenames or symlink targets that contain newline characters.

Comment: Also note that it gives the sum of the file sizes, not their disk usage. For symlinks, it gives the size of the symlinks, not the files they point to.

Answer (score 2):

Improving SHW's great answer to make it work with any locale, like Zbyszek already pointed out in his comment:

```
LC_ALL=C find ./photos/john_doe -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$
```

Answer (score 2):

du naturally traverses the directory hierarchy and awk can perform the filtering so something like this may be sufficient:

```
du -ak | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} /\.jpg$/ {sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

This works without GNU.

Comment: This is more expensive since it entails a `stat` call for files that do not correspond to the searched-for pattern.

Comment: Only this solution works on my mac.

Comment: It assumes file names don't contain newline characters and that there's no directory whose name ends in `.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

```
find -type f -iname *.jpg -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- | grep total$
```

Comment: This is more or less a copy of [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148472/116858) (apart from the trivial `grep` at the end).

Answer (score 2):

Using the modern `fd` (AKA `fd-find` or `fdfind` on Ubuntu)

```
fdfind -e jpg -X du -ch | tail -1
```

I found `fd` easier to work with then `find`, and no need to enable `globstar`

The trick is to use the uppercase `X` --exec-batch that executes the command just once and not the lowercase `x`, which does a normal `exec` running on every file.

To install on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install fd-find
```

[See more](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

Answer (score 0):

Another would be

```
ls -al <directory> | awk '{t+=$5}END{print t}}'
```

Assuming you're looking in a single directory.  If you want to look at the current directory and beneath that

```
ls -Ral <directory> | awk '{t+=$5}END{print t}}'
```

Comment: (1) Biggest problem: This looks at *everything,* but the question is specifically about restricting the search to a subset of files; e.g., `*.jpg`.  (And the question explicitly says that the OP wants to do a recursive directory search.)  (2) This will count, not only files with non-matching names (e.g., `*.gif`, `*.png`, etc.), but also non-files; e.g., directories and symbolic links.  (3) This can produce incorrect results if any filename(s) contain newline(s).  (4) Like some of the (poorer) answers, this counts hard links multiple times.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Hint: When a question is almost 8 years old and has 9 answers, it's quite possible that all the good answers have already been given, and you should think long and hard about whether you *really* have something new and better to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative using stat rather than du

```
stat -L -c %s ** | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}'
```

See Gilles answer about using **

Answer (score 0):

This is a mashup of several answers and comments that do what I need.

`find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.png" \) -type f -exec du -bc {} + | grep total$ | cut -f1 | awk '{ total += $1 }; END { print total }'| numfmt --to=iec`

- `find` will get all the files recursively
- `-iname` is for case INsensitive
- `-o` and parenthesis to look for multiple patterns
- `du -bc` will get the files' size, sometimes in more than one call if there are many files
- `grep total` will get only the `total` line as given by `du`
- `cut -f1` will take only the actual integer values
- `awk` will sum them all
- `numfmt` will convert it to a human-readable format

Comment: It won't work if current locale displays totals with a label that differs from "total"