# calculate total used disk space by files older than 1000 days using find

Tags: linux, find, disk-usage

We have more than 4 years of data in our system. We need to move 2 years old files and directories in a new repository. Our requirement is needed to know how many TB of data from Jan 2017 to as of now 2.Exclude personal folder I tried to find command but couldn't work out.

```bash
find . -type f -mtime +1010 ! -path "./home/01_Personal Folder*" -printf '%s\n' \ 
| awk '{a+=$1;} END {printf "%.1f GB\n", a/2**30;}'
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41550/find-the-total-size-of-certain-files-within-a-directory-branch

Comment: I think you should present your commands seperately, the find and the awk. Possibly duplicated? Yes but not in the sense "already answered". I think `find -type f ... |awk` and `find -type d ... du {}` both make sense

Comment: Oh from Jan 2017 to now, that would rather be -1000. Good trick with the 1000 and **TEN**! (besides the usual extra confusion and lack of info or clear language)

Answer (score 2):

Could be something similar to:

```
find . ! -path "./home/01_Personal Folder*" -type f -mtime +1000 -exec du -ch {} + | grep total
```

Answer based on: [Find the total size of certain files within a directory branch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41550/find-the-total-size-of-certain-files-within-a-directory-branch)

[Explain shell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20%21%20-path%20%22.%2Fhome%2F01_Personal%20Folder*%22%20-type%20f%20-mtime%20%2B1000%20-exec%20du%20-ch%20%7B%7D%20%2B%20%7C%20grep%20total) command.

Comment: it's the folder to be excluded...

Comment: I want to exclude /home/01_Personal Folder*"

Comment: Added the exclude /home/01_Personal Folder*" option

Comment: @PauloTomé You found that pipe here, and you say "could be ...". And you are "new". And two upvotes.  But I tested the `-exec du` and soon found a problem. I put it at the top of my answer. I edited quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
37M     total
29M     total
42M     total
43M     total
36M     total

real    0m1.271s
user    0m0.561s
sys     0m1.278s
```

Is what I get with:

`time find ~/sda1 -type f -exec du -ch {} +|grep total`

So now I need a tool to sum up the totals! (This is a `-exec...+` overflow)

But with:

`time find ~/sda1 -type f -printf "%s\n" | awk '{a+=$1;} END {print a;}'`

```
10483650002

real    0m0.550s
user    0m0.251s
sys     0m0.349s
```

And:

```
]# time du ~/sda1 -sh
11G     /.../sda1

real    0m0.458s
user    0m0.116s
sys     0m0.340s
```

I get it nice and fast.

---

It seems inefficient to `du` each file, when find is `stat`ing them anyway, and can give the size for free. With `find ... -exec du {} +`, `du` is degraded to a calculator of -c "grand total".

There is of course some difference between file size (in bytes) and disk usage (in blocks).

---

Here just to show that the original `find ... -printf "%s\n" | awk '{...} END {...}' works:

```
]# find ~ -maxdepth 1 -printf "%s\n" | awk '{a+=$1;} END {print a;}'
1093990
]# find ~ -maxdepth 1 -printf "%s\n" | awk '{a+=$1;} END {printf "%x\n",a;}'
10b166
```

This is my first `awk` ever.

I tested this on `~ -maxdepth 1`, and the round number struck me, and that "GB" thing at the end of OP, so I played around until I got 10**6 = 16x64K.